# Why the form filled data using html and javascript is not getting added into the firebase database (V9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried many different codes and ways in my project but don't know the reason why the data is not getting added to the firebase database.

Can I get to know where I am making mistakes or what changes should be done.
Can I please get the complete code which can help me to add the filled data by the user into the form.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Investors Hub</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--jquery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="signupdiv">
            <div class="container">
                <form action="" id="signform">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" id="name" required>
                    <label for="age"><b>Age</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" id="age" required>
                    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" id="email" required>
                    <label for="mobile"><b>Mobile Number</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile No." id="mobile" required>
                    <label for="user"><b>Username</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" id="user" required>
                    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" id="psw" required>
                    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                    <input class="signin" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" id="psw-repeat" required>
                    <button style="background-color: rgb(34, 156, 9); margin-left: 50px;"class="loginbutton">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="module">
            // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
            import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.17.1/firebase-app.js";

                const firebaseConfig = {
                    apiKey: "AIzaSyBJhHYCreSFrPNK6sU0O6IVv0a49C5EeRQ",
                    authDomain: "projectfirebase-4cbe6.firebaseapp.com",
                    projectId: "projectfirebase-4cbe6",
                    storageBucket: "projectfirebase-4cbe6.appspot.com",
                    messagingSenderId: "250201013862",
                    appId: "1:250201013862:web:01d5b87765bb91d99937a7"
                };
         
                const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
         
                var messagesRef = database().ref('Collected Data');
                 
                document.getElementById('signform')
                    .addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
         
                function submitForm(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
         
                    // Get values
                    var name = getInputVal('name');
                    var age=getInputVal('age');
                    var email = getInputVal('email');
                    var mobile=getInputVal('mobile');
                    var username=getInputVal('username');
                    var pass=getInputVal('psw');
         
                    saveMessage(name, age, email, mobile, username, pass);
                    document.getElementById('signform').reset();
                }
         
                // Function to get form values
                function getInputVal(id) {
                    return document.getElementById(id).value;
                }
         
                // Save message to firebase
                function saveMessage(name, age, email, mobile, username, pass) {
                    var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
                    newMessageRef.set({
                        name: name,
                        age: age,
                        email: email,
                        mobile: mobile,
                        username: username,
                        pass:pass
                    });
                }
            </script>
            
    </body>

    
    
</html>
```